# ReactiveCocoa RACObserve self model trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa, racsignal

I have a model in my ViewController (ex `@property (nonatomic, strong) Model *model;`)

There are 2 properties (`property1` , `property2`).

I'm trying to observe these properties via `RACObserve` macro and then use `combineLatest`

```
RACSignal *sig1 = [RACObserve(self.model, property1] map // Map block
RACSignal *sig2 = [RACObserve(self.model, property2] map // Map block
NSArray *signals = @[sig1, sig2];
RAC(self, userHasChangedSomething) = [[RACSignal combineLatest:signals] or];
[RACObserve(self, userHasChangedSomething) subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *hasChangedNumber) {
            BOOL hasChanged = [hasChangedNumber boolValue];
            self->sendButton.enabled = hasChanged;
            self->sendButton.alpha = hasChanged ? 1.f : 0.4f;
        }];
```

Can you explain me why if I use `RACObserve(self.model, property1)` it doesn't triggered `combineLatest` and nothing happens in `subscribeNext`. But if I change to `RACObserve(self, model.property)` then works good. I cannot understand this. Could you help me out. Thanks in advance.